# C# multiple pages on a form

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm searching for something like this video here shows: [C# Tutorial: Multiple Pages on the Form (Using Panels)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDOXzz_0gYE)

It's the only thing I've found so far for "paged" forms, I don't even know if this is the right search term (comment if you know how this is called). The video explains what I want to do, but I think there must be a better way to do this than just stacking many panels, it seems pretty messy/hacky.

Is this the way to go or have you a better idea to achieve "pages" on a form?

*I'm currently using .NET 3.5 but everything else is also fine (including WPF), I can easily switch if necessary.*

Comment: i think wpf gives you more options to make application with such a behavior, like using NavigationWindow. check [this](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation) or [this one](http://wbswiki.com/doku.php?id=notes:wpf:pagesnav)

Comment: Thank you for the links, seems like I should look into WPF a bit to see if it fits my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have "multiple pages" on the same form, then stacking multiple controls on top of each other and changing their visibility is a pretty sensible approach.

Of course, you would probably want to do it programatically.

1. Define your "views" or "pages" as separate `UserControl`s, exposing a common interface which would allow you to perform actions common to all pages.

   ```
   // easily created in Visual Studio designer
   public partial class FirstPage : UserControl
   { ... }
   ```
2. Add them to your `Form` programmatically (`parentContainer.Controls.Add(...)`).

   ```
   public partial class WizardForm : Form
   {
       public WizardForm()
       {
            InitializeComponent();

            // _container is a panel, tabpage, or whatever you want to
            // keep your "pages" in
            _container.Controls.AddRange(pagesList);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Will try this out today and report back/accept if it works.